# java date pattern for timezone without ":"

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, timezone-offset, date-parsing

I will work with third party API. They accept a date pattern like:

```
2012-02-15T17:34:37.937-0600
```

I know the pattern should be match like

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.s
```

But I am not sure how to represent the last "-0600" timezone? I think the standard timezone is "-06:00", anyone knows how to get rid of the ":" in the date pattern?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

maybe you want "Z" ?

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html:

> - 'z' gives you "Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00"
> - 'Z' gives you "-0800"

This code:

```
final SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ");
```

produces:

> 2012-05-11T12:21:57.598+1000

Comment: @ttt: Note also the uppercase 'S' for milliseconds (differs from your question's datespec) and the single quotes around 'T'.

Answer (score 1):

java.text.SimpleDateFormat should be very helpful for customize the string representation:

Z  Time zone  RFC 822 time zone  -0800

Answer (score 0):

> I know the pattern should be match like
>
> `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.s`

No, there are two problems in this pattern:

1. The symbol for fraction-of-second is `S`, but you have used `s`.
2. The `ZoneOffset` specifier, `Z` is missing in the pattern.

### java.time

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10544551/10819573) uses `SimpleDateFormat` which was the correct thing to do in 2012. In Mar 2014, the `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` were supplanted by the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html). Since then, it is highly recommended to stop using the legacy date-time API.

**Demo using the modern date-time API**:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.of("-06:00")).format(dtf));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-12-28T13:21:05.459-0600
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/m025WO)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.